# Simple Dictionary Search Component in SharePoint

Tags: list, search

How would you implement a small dictionary search?(not more than 300 entries).
I have a list in which I use abbreviations/words and description of the term, and I would like to make a functionality on a site page in which I have an input box and a search button and a result zone.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you could build such component using OOTB:

1. Using Managed metadata synonims - limited but OOTB

or

1. Create a new Content type, e.g. Acronym (only for reusability purposes) with following columns:

   - ID, Title (OOTB fields) and optionally add others such as Description
2. Create DataView (or XSLT View) web part which you customize to your needs via SPD to enable filter by parameter including multiple columns, such as TITLE contains {keyword} OR Description contains {keyword} (standard filtering procedures in SPD 2010)
3. Use a TEXT Field web part which connected to the DataView web part would send Filtering Parameters

More complicated solutions are based on development if you wish,
C:\Marius

Answer (score 1):

The best thing would be:

- Create a content type + list with abbreviation and description
- create a page using search web parts limited to the list
- create a page using search web parts limited to the content type so the list can be distributed between sites

SharePoint search is very powerful so it would be a waste not using it whenever you want to do any searching